# Save data into two tables at same time in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, model, eloquent

I am trying to save datas into two different tables depends on selection(x-editable). Here is my code and Help me by pointing where i am doing mistake.

Result i am looking for: I change payment status pending to paid in TBL:Product, paid values also change 0 to 1 in TBL:Product_payment

**TBL:Product**

```
- product_id
- client_id
...
- status {paid/pending}
```

**TBL:Product_payment**

```
- product_id
- payment_id
....
- paid {1/0}
```

**Controller:**

```
public function update()
{

    $inputs = Input::all();
        if ($row = Product::with('payments')->find($inputs['pk']))
        {   
            $row->$inputs['name'] = $inputs['value'];
            if($row['status'] == 'paid') {
                $row['paid'] = 1;
            }
            $row->save();
            return $row;

}
```

**Product.php(model)**

```
class Product extends Eloquent
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'product_id';
    protected $table = 'products';

    protected $fillable = array('client_id', 'date', 'amount', 'status', 'notes');

    public function payments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('ProductPayment');
    }

}
```

**ProductPayment.php(model)**

```
class ProductPayment extends Eloquent
{
    public $table = 'product_payments';
    protected $primaryKey = 'product_payment_id';


    protected $fillable = array('product_id', 'client_id', 'payment_method', 'amount_paid', 'paid');

    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Products');
    }

    public function clients()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Clients');
    }
}
```

Comment: Anyone, please let me know if my question is unclear to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add [a model event listener](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#events) to `boot` in your `AppServiceProvider` for whenever an instance of `Product` is saved.

```
Product::saved(function ($product) {
    $paymentStatus = [
        'pending' => 0,
        'paid' => 1,
    ]; 

    if(array_key_exists($product->status, $paymentStatus))
    {
       ProductPayment::where('product_id', $product->id)
           ->update(['paid' => $paymentStatus[$product->status]]);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you @Oluwafemi Sule your answer is very useful.